# Is there anything in CQ API to allow you to create a node from a cq:component?

Tags: aem

I'm curious about whether or not there is something in the CQ API that will allow me to create a node based on a `cq:component`, much like what would happen when an author adds a component to a parsys.

Because I needed to get the piece done, I went ahead and did it manually. I've included this solution to see if someone can go "oh man there's this .* method you can use to do exactly that".

This is what I'm doing:

```
public static Node createFromComponent(Node dstParent, Node srcComponent, String targetName) {
    Node newNode = null;

    try {
        //if there is a template use it
        if (srcComponent.hasNode("cq:template")) {
            newNode = JcrUtil.copy(srcComponent.getNode("cq:template"), dstParent, targetName);
        }
        else {
            newNode = dstParent.addNode(targetName);
        }

        //set the resourceType to the path of the component sent over
        newNode.setProperty("sling:resourceType", srcComponent.getPath());

        newNode.getSession().save();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error creating node from component: ", e);
    }

    return newNode;
}
```

It's pretty straight forward. I was looking at the [`JcrUtil` Class](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html), but I don' t think it has what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in method that:

1. copies contents of the `cq:template` node or
2. creates a new node,
3. sets a `sling:resourceType` property to the node.

When you drag the component from sidekick to parsys, your browser sends a HTTP POST request to the Sling. If the target component contains `cq:template` subnode, this HTTP request will contain an additional property:

```
./@CopyFrom:/apps/my/component/cq:template
```

which takes care of setting default values. Because you want to do the same thing via API rather than HTTP request, you need a custom method.

Answer (score 2):

You could go a level higher & use the Sling API rather than JCR. If you adapt the `cq:template` node to a ValueMap & then pass it to the [`ResourceResolver.create()`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html#create%28org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) method…

E.g.

```
<%  
    Resource templateAsResource = resourceResolver.resolve("/path/to/cq:template");
    ValueMap templateProperties = templateAsResource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
    resourceResolver.create(parentResource, "newResource", templateProperties);
    resourceResolver.commit();
%>
```

Have given this a quick test locally — it works in Author mode when authenticated. (If you're running it in a Publish instance or as a non-admin user, you may need a few extra lines to ensure you have permissions both to create the node but also to read the **cq:template** file under `/apps`)

Comment: Please notice that `cq:template` node may also have children which should be copied recursively.

Comment: @TomekRękawek, Yes, good point! Generally I only use `cq:template` for properties, so wasn't considering children.

Comment: @anotherdave thank you for this, we have a lot of places were this could become applicable, but per my question I was curious if there was something built in, however, thank you for this, it's a reminder of how much more I need to learn about sling.